# Updating a prototype using an instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have this constructor function `Person`:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

I added an array `favorites` on the its prototype so that all instances of  `Person` can point to this same array:

```
Person.prototype.favorites = [];
```

```
var person1 = new Person("KimK");
var person2 = new Person("KhloeK");

person1.favorites = ["coke"]; 
person2.favorites = ["pepsi"];

console.log(person1.favorites); //["coke"]
console.log(person2.favorites); //["pepsi"]
```

I expected both the log statements to print `["pepsi"]` since both `person1` and `person2` point to the same base array `favorites` on the prototype, and since `person2` modified it at last to `["pepsi"]`, I expected the both the outputs to be `["pepsi"]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is impossible,because person 1 & person 2 are two different instance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reading object properties can involve searching through the inheritance chain.**

Reading a javascript object property first searches through the local property names of the object. If not found as a local or ["own" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), searching continues by looking at each prototype object in the inheritance chain in turn until the property name is found or all objects in the inheritance chain have been examined. If the name was found, its value is obtained from the object where it was found. If not found  reading returns `undefined` as the named property value.

**Writing object properties always* writes property values locally**

Writing the value of a named value property creates or updates a local property value held by the object being written to. If it was previously inherited through inheritance chain it will stop being inherited: reading returns the local value in preference. Note the inherited property value of the object it was inherited from remains unchanged.

**So**

```
person1.favorites = ["coke"]; 
person2.favorites = ["pepsi"];
```

creates a new local `favorites` property of `person1` before writing `["coke"]` to it, and a new local `favorites` property of `person2` before writing `["pepsi"]`to it.

A previous `favorites` property value inherited from `Person.prototype`, [], becomes hidden in the process.

---

***Getters and Setters defined in ES5 excluded**

[Setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) functions associate a property name with an object. Property names set up in this way lack an internal [[value]] slot but are inheritable as getter and setter functions. In particular writing to an object does search the inheritance chain for a **setter** if a local property of the same name does not already exist.

Although getters and setters are called with the object being read or written as their `this` value, where and how they store and retrieve values cannot be generalized because it depends on how they are written.

Comment: `"Writing object properties always writes property values locally"`. Note that there is an exception to that when the prototype's property is a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Comment: @Paulpro thanks for the note - I've updated the reply to cover changes to the model made in ES5.

Answer (score 2):

This assigns a new array to person1's favorites property. It doesn't modify the existing one on its prototype:

```
person1.favorites = ["coke"];
```

You can append to an array using push and you can empty an array by setting its length to 0. As an example:

```
person1.favorites.push( 'coke' );
person2.favorites.length = 0;        
person2.favorites.push( 'coke' );
```

Comment: Great answer, by using push() why it is not creating a new array on the instance ?

Comment: @WildWidow push modifies the array instead of creating a new one.

Comment: so we are able to modify the prototype using an instance right?

Comment: @WildWidow Not exactly, you can't modify the prototype through an instance , but if the prototype has any objects (including arrays) on it, you can modify those objects.

Answer (score 1):

When you're assigning `["coke"]` to `person1.favorites`, you're modifying a property of `person1`, not the `Person` prototype. You can easily check this by `console.log(Person.prototype.favorites)` — it still contains empty array. If you want to change the value for all instances, the only way is to directly modify the prototype, i.e.:

```
Person.prototype.favorites = ["coke"];
```

However, if you didn't set a `favorites` property to `Person` instances, you can modify the prototype by modifying `person1.favorites`. For example:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.favorites = [];

var person1 = new Person("KimK");
person1.favorites.push("coke", "pepsi")

console.log(person1.favorites); // ["coke", "pepsi"]

var person2 = new Person("KhloeK");
console.log(person2.favorites); // ["coke", "pepsi"]

console.log(Person.prototype.favorites); // ["coke", "pepsi"]
```

Comment: thanks for console.log(Person.prototype.favorites), I have upvoted you to neutralize the downvote, I believe we can still modify the array on the prototype using an instance by using push method on the array

Comment: @WildWidow No, you can't modify prototype by modifying an instance. Anyway, what do you want it for?

Comment: person1.favorites.push( 'coke' );   - does not create a new favorites on person1 instance , instead it goes to the favorites array on the prototype. So this means we are modifying the prototype through an instance right?

Comment: @WildWidow No. `person1.favorites.push('coke');` adds a new element to `person1.favorites`. It doesn't modify prototype.

Comment: I did person1.favorites.push( "coke" ); and person2.favorites.push( "pepsi" );  and did console log on person1.favorites and person2.favorites, both printed  ["coke", "pepsi"]   which means we modified the favorites on the prototype

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108585/discussion-between-wild-widow-and-gothdo).